# Injecting a SessionScoped Bean inside a View Scoped bean in JSF

Tags: java, primefaces

I am building a web application in JSF 2.0 using Prime faces 4.0.In my project I have image upload feature for this I have used  of Prime Faces. My requirement is this:there is a Choose button through which user will browse and then through Upload button
image will be uploaded,but it will not be saved in database.There is a separate save button in the page on clicking the save button image will get saved in database.

But my problem is that::For uploading image I have a managedBean calle ImageController.java which is in SessionScoped and the save button consist of a actionlistener method which is defined inside a managedBean class which is in ViewScoped.

I am providing the code of ImageController.java class

```
   package com.edfx.tum.web.controller;

   import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
   import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
   import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
   import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
   import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
   import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;
   import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
   import com.edfx.tum.dto.UserDTO;


  @SessionScoped
  @ManagedBean(name = "imageController")
  public class ImageController extends BaseWebController implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -3975946403680318499L;

 private StreamedContent image;
 private byte[] uploadedImage;



public void initImage() {

    UserDTO user = getCurrentUser();
    byte[] img = user.getUserPhoto();
    setUploadedImage(img);
    if (img != null) {
        image = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(img));
    } else {
        image = null;
    }
}

public StreamedContent getImage() {
    return this.image;
}



public byte[] getUploadedImage() {
    return uploadedImage;
}

public void setUploadedImage(byte[] uploadedImage) {
    this.uploadedImage = uploadedImage;
}


public void setImage(StreamedContent image) {
    this.image = image;
}


@PostConstruct
public void init() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    initImage();
}

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();

    byte[] img = uploadedFile.getContents();

    image = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(img));
    setUploadedImage(img);
 }
}
```

The name of the managedBean to which save button's actionlistener is bind is UserDetailsController and in tghe following way I have injected the dependency into UserDetailscontroller.java class

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "userDetailsController")
public class UserDetailsController extends BaseWebController implements Serializable {
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{imageController}")
private ImageController imageController;

public ImageController getImageController() {
    return imageController;
}

public void setImageController(ImageController imageController) {
    this.imageController = imageController;
 }

  //other codes here

  public void submit(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    try {
        UserDTO userDTO = (UserDTO) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("user");
        if (userDTO != null) {
            userDTO.setUserPhoto(imageController.getUploadedImage());
            processDBPeopleUpdate(userDTO);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LoggingUtils.printStackTrace(e, log);
    }
  }  
}
```

donot worry about the "processDBPeopleUpdate(userDTO);" code it just normal saveOrUpdate() method for saving the dto to database.

below is the piece of xhtml code::

```
  <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" styleClass="imageStyle" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="myProfileForm:growl myProfileForm:profileImage"     sizeLimit="1000000" fileUploadListener="#{imageController.handleFileUpload}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpeg|png|tiff|exif)$/"/>
```

Now,the problem I am facing is that after clicking the save button picture is getting saved in database.but once I changed the tab for example:**This functionality is in "My Profile" tab now after saving the image in database if I change the tap to User(suppose),from again I goto My Profile tab the picture is not showing**

again If I logout then do login and go to "my profile tab" again the picture is  showing.So,In a word I want to say that image is not persisting upon tab change.

can anyone give any suitable solution to this?

Comment: So really you have no issue with CDI Bean injection it's to do with render/save of your data? - the xhtml would be nice to see what your update / render sections are like, also your database is kind of important if it's not saving properly then of course it's not going to show it!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the StreamedContent in your xhtml. If so, the problem is you don't update the `imageController.image` attribute when you set the `uploadedImage` in your `userDetailsController`. You only initialize this attribute on `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: ImageController class is in sessionscope and during invocation of handleFileUpload() method I am setting the image attribute with newly uploaded value.So,it should persist.

Comment: can you attach you xhtml too please? Maybe it should help us. Also, are you using el caching or view pooling?